# On the appstore which text will appear

Tags: ios, app-store, review

I have a concern about the app store.I will send to review an ios app but which name will appear on the app store I'm not sure.

https://ibb.co/3R5xfW4

For example on this image you will see bold text this is app name and gray text it's a subtitle but under the gray text, there is a blue and bold text.I don't know which name on my membership. If it is copyright, seller name, account holder name or developer name, I don't know.

Which name will appear instead of this blue bold text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is account holder name. for more info check screen shot.I have attached apple developer account snap with red circle and also attached app store snap with red circle.

[image]

[image]

Comment: unfornutely this link is broken I can not see your screenshot but my membership is as an organization this is important thing, and now my account holder name is my name.So you mean, if I publish this app my name will appear on the appstore because I dont want to appear my name.

Comment: Yes, your name will appear

Comment: Thank you  Vinod ,but I don't want to appear this, my seller name is my company name right now, but Can I change my account holder name to my company name for appear on appstore ?

Comment: yeah I accepted thank you again but Can I change my account holder name to my company name directly.

Comment: No, you can request to apple with company document. They review all documents and change your account individual to company.